# What makes a space a real space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, space

By "[real space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_space)" I mean a space in which physical particles move.

Consider a color sphere and let a bunch of objects "move" on its surface. "Move" means "change colors". Let there be some rules governing the changes of color, maybe giving rise to something like inertness or collisions. .

> Under which conditions will we be willing or
>   forced to think of the movements as
>   real movements in real space?

[image]

Comment: Please stop with this "philosophy" tag: either your question is a valid question about physics as a science and it doesn't need this tag or this is not a valid question and it should be closed.

Comment: I removed it. Maybe one should lock this tag?

Comment: Well, is your colored sphere model describing a real colored sphere, or is it just a model for some other phenomenon where color and sphere are just concepts introduced to visualize some more complicated stuff? Think for instance about the name color for some properties of quarks. Do quarks really have a color like in the sense an apple is red? No. But quarks do have a property that we could have called schmutz or pop or color, it just became color because of aesthetical reasons, because of the analogy with RGB color system of TV (which is not really very deep, just the number of colors).

Comment: Well, I suppose "color" to be any (abstract) property with a metric (?) on its values such that they can be arranged on a sphere.

Comment: What I have in mind: "location" is not a property like any other. But why? (In ancient times one believed, that no two particles can be at the same place at the same time. This would be a difference to "normal" properties.)

Comment: This doesn't really seem like physics to me, I'm afraid. Mathematics, at best. It's not a very well-specified problem though, even.

Comment: I admit. But I am afraid that mathematicians won't understand the question: they don't have the concept of "real space".

Comment: @Noldorin: Do you at least have a premonition of what I am asking?

Comment: This is possibly an interesting problem but you have to make it clear what exactly you are after. For one thing, try to formulate it mathematically. "Color" doesn't really tell me anything. What I read is that you have *foobars* moving by the means of *foobar laws*. This has no mathematical content (not to mention physical). Also, what precisely is *real movement* and *real space*?

Comment: @Hans: I've never encountered the term "real space" before, but it seems to just be 3-dimensional Euclidian space. The whole idea of colours in confusing me though. It sounds like you're describing a *scalar field*.

Comment: @Marek: OK, I will work the question over. But it will be hard to define "real space" mathematically, since modelled mathematically you cannot distinguish between the surface of a concrete solid sphere and an abstract "color" sphere: they both are modelled by $S^2$.

Comment: @Noldorin: Euclidean space is a purely mathematical abstract concept, real space is (locally) isomorphic to Euclidean space, but a physical concrete concept.

Comment: @Noldorin: In German there's the term *Ortsraum* (see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortsraum) which translates to *real space* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_space).

Comment: Real space if not a very well defined concept: we just use it when we want to distinguish from another space we are using, like reciprocal space.

Comment: "Configuration space" is more abstract than "real space". Please note that "Euclidean space" is per se void of physical meaning: it's a mathematical concept (at least as I understand it). So how do you call the space surrounding us?

Comment: When I am talking to my mother I don't use the word "space" and when I am solving a physical problem I formulate it mathematically... What's the difference between your question and "Why would we interpret something that seems to move as something really moving ?" ?

Comment: The idea of Euclidian space is very much tied in with the physical reality. Newtonian physics only works in a *Euclidian space*, and GR talks about differential manifolds that reduce to Euclidian space on a small-enough scale.

Comment: @Noldorin just a nitpick: GR talks about local reductions to **Minkowski** space-time. They are **Lorentzian** manifolds, not **Riemannian**. Just for the record, both Gauss and Riemann considered the curvature of **space** (and Gauss also came with ways of actually measuring it) but it was Einstein who really first came with the idea of curvature of the space-time (mainly because there was no knowledge of space-time before the advent of Special Relativity).

Comment: @Marek: Sure, which can further be reduced to Euclidean space in the appropriate limit. :) And yes, Gauss and Riemann pioneered the math, but in my view that was the easy(ier) bit! There was no physical insight involved, or even a suggestion it applied to reality.

Comment: @Noldorin: I think you are doing a great disservice to Gauss here. While its true that he was one of the greatest mathematicians, you also shouldn't forget about a dozen of basic physical laws named after him ;-) In particular that curvature of the space can actually be *measured* (e.g. you measure the angles and area of some triangle). What can be more physical than that? As for the Riemann, I am not really sure about his connections to physics (of course except for the fact that many of his discoveries are fundamental to huge portion of physics).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that the way we perceive reality is governed by physical laws as well. In your coloured sphere model, the coloured sphere people would perceive the changing of colour as we perceive movement.

In fact, it is quite customary in physics to think using completely abstract representations of space, and only ultimately reduce the equations to real space. In other words there are [representations of the universe which do not resemble real space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space), but are equally as valid.